# Hwo to fix error in WordPress Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom functionality in WooCommerce and it is about the filtering. If you choose any filter from the sidebar of the eshop and then browse to a single product page you'll have navigation arrows based on your previous selection filtering. It works fine but only in a specific product i get the error

**Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in functions.php on line 355**

```
function filter_single_post_pagination($output, $format, $link, $post){
    $variable = $_GET;

    if (count($variable) == 0) {
        $url       = get_permalink($post->ID);
        if (isset($post->ID)) {
            if('previous_post_link' === current_filter()){
                return "<a href='$url' rel='next'>→</a>";
            } else {
                return "<a href='$url' rel='prev'>←</a>";
            }
        } 
    }

    else {
        $pids = array();
        $product_ids = "";
        foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
            $product_ids .= $key."&";
            array_push($pids, $key);
        }

        global $product;
        $id = $product->get_id();
        $key_val = array_search($id,$pids);
        $custom_link = "?".$product_ids;


        if (isset($pids[$key_val+1])) {
            if('previous_post_link' === current_filter()){
                $rel  = 'next';
                $next_url       = get_permalink($pids[$key_val+1]);
                return "<a href='$next_url.$custom_link' rel='$rel'>→</a>";
            }
        }

        if (isset($pids[$key_val-1])) {
            if('next_post_link' === current_filter()){
                $rel  = 'prev';
                $previous_url   = get_permalink($pids[$key_val-1]);
                return "<a href='$previous_url.$custom_link' rel='$rel'>←</a>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show how you execute this function?

Comment: your if that checks the `ID` for existence is useless since the line above it uses it outright

Comment: You have to check using print_r($post);